# HTTPS URL of Rundeck Not working from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, https, rundeck

I'm trying to integrate Rundeck from Jenkins. I'm configuring it from 'Manager Jenkins -> Configure Systems'

HTTP connection to the Rundeck is working fine, whereas HTTPS URL for the same Rundeck instance is not working. Getting below Exception:
We couldn't find a live Rundeck instance at https://yyyy.yyyy.net:4443

Jenkins - 2.181
Rundeck - 3.0.22
Rundeck Plugin from Jenkins - 3.6.5

Is there anything else I should check?

Answer (score 0):

Seems an unresolved Jenkins Rundeck Plugin issue, check that: https://github.com/vbehar/jenkins-rundeck-plugin/issues/19